# Hibernate global "dynamic-insert"

Tags: hibernate

Is there way to set the `dynamic-insert` attribute globally with Hibernate (so it would be the default for all entities) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in NHibernate it is

```
foreach (var clazz in config.ClassMappings)
{
    clazz.DynamicInsert = true;
}
```

i don't know the exact syntax in hibernate.

```
for (PersistentClass clazz : configuration.ClassMappings)
{
    clazz.setDynamicInsert(true);
}
```

Comment: Hmm didn't see anything that reminds this method in `ClassMetaData`, but there is a `PersistentClass.setDynamicInsert(boolean)` method. Will have to see if it helps me somehow

Answer (score 1):

For Java Hibernate, the correct answer is:

```
Iterator mappingClasses = config.getClassMappings();
while(mappingClasses.hasNext()) {
   PersistentClass clazz = (PersistentClass) mappingClasses.next();
   clazz.setDynamicInsert(true);
   clazz.setDynamicUpdate(true);
}
```

Keep in mind that you have to build the mappings before you attempt to iterate over them. Otherwise `config.getClassMappings()` will return empty iterator.

```
config.buildMappings();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple integrator that reads the persistence.xml and modifies hibernates boot metadata:

```java
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.engine.config.spi.ConfigurationService;
import org.hibernate.engine.config.spi.StandardConverters;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor;
import org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator;
import org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass;
import org.hibernate.service.spi.SessionFactoryServiceRegistry;
import org.immutables.metainf.Metainf;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Metainf.Service(Integrator.class)
public class DynamicUpdateIntegrator implements Integrator {
  private static final String SETTING = "hibernate.dynamic_update";
  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

  @Override
  public void integrate(Metadata metadata, SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
      SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
    ConfigurationService cfgService = serviceRegistry.getService(ConfigurationService.class);
    Boolean shouldUseDynamicUpdate = cfgService.getSetting(SETTING, StandardConverters.BOOLEAN, null);
    if (shouldUseDynamicUpdate == null) {
      return;
    }

    logger.info("Setting dynamic update to {} for all entities.", shouldUseDynamicUpdate);
    for (PersistentClass persistentClass : metadata.getEntityBindings()) {
      persistentClass.setDynamicUpdate(shouldUseDynamicUpdate);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void disintegrate(SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {}
}
```

Then add this line to your persistence.xml:

```xml
<property name="hibernate.dynamic_update" value="true" />
```

Note that this code makes use of the annotation processor `org.immutables:metainf:2.9.0` to add the full qualified classname of `DynamicUpdateIntegrator`  to the file `META-INF/services/org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator`. You can instead use https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/service to achieve the same or manually create and update that file.